# PHP Array - how to extract part of it

Tags: php, arrays, nusoap

I want to get from one big array some values received by SOAP service.

```
printr($result)
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [GetProductResult] => Array
        (
            [schema] => Array
                (
                    [element] => Array
                        (
                            [complexType] => Array
                                (
                                    [choice] => Array
                                        (
                                            [element] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [complexType] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [sequence] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [element] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [!name] => codigo
                                                                                    [!minOccurs] => 0
                                                                                )

                                                                            [1] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [!name] => nome
                                                                                    [!minOccurs] => 0
                                                                                )

                                                                            [2] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [!name] => imagem
                                                                                    [!minOccurs] => 0
                                                                                )

                                                                            [3] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [!name] => stock
                                                                                    [!minOccurs] => 0
                                                                                )

                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [!name] => produto
                                                )

                                            [!minOccurs] => 0
                                            [!maxOccurs] => unbounded
                                        )

                                )

                            [!name] => produtos
                            [!msdata:IsDataSet] => true
                            [!msdata:UseCurrentLocale] => true
                        )

                    [!id] => produtos
                )

            [diffgram] => Array
                (
                    [produtos] => Array
                        (
                            [produto] => Array
                                (
                                    [codigo] => 37527
                                    [nome] => Macally - Caixa 2.5" USB2 para discos SATA
                                    [imagem] => http://www.macally-europe.com/img/products/ProductImage1987.jpg
                                    [stock] => 1
                                    [!diffgr:id] => produto1
                                    [!msdata:rowOrder] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I just want that get values from the last part of array:

```
diffgram -> produtos -> produto -> [codigo],[nome],[imagem],[stock]
```

Comment: Holy arrays of arrays, Batman!

Comment: I feel like I am falling—sideways.

Comment: Is it always going to be called diffgram?

Comment: and where's the problem? Just access those properties as you would access any other PHP array, with the difference that this one is nested deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$produto = $array['GetProductResult']['diffgram']['produtos']['produto'];
echo $produto['codigo'];
echo $produto['nome'];
echo $produto['imagem'];
echo $produto['stock'];
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$result['GetProductResult']['diffgram']['produtos']['produto']
```

The codigo, nom, imagem, and stock keys are in that array.

Answer (score 0):

Try flattening the array first (source [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)):

```
function flatten(array $array) {
    $return = array();
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[] = $a; });
    return $return;
}

$arr = flatten($arr);
```

Then access it by using $arr['diffgram'], $arr['produto'], etc...